# Why out of money options show no bid price but a valid ask price

Tags: call-options, expiration

Looking at the option chain for [SPY](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=SPY)

I see that a lot of the out of the money calls are showing Bid as N/A. What is the reason? Nobody wants to buy out of the money calls because expiration is approaching?

It seems odd that nobody wants to buy but so many people want to sell these for 0.01. Why would someone want to sell for 0.01? 0.01 does not even cover commission on the trade.

Comment: If they're really being offered for $0.01, that's probably being offered by institutions which do not have commission costs. And bid is N/A because, yes, nobody sane thinks they're worth the effort of buying even at that price.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the SPY option chain you posted, all of the call options with a strike price of 199.50 or higher have a bid of N/A.  That's because the ask price for all of those options is 0.01, and the bid price has to be less than the ask price, but buyers are not allowed to bid 0.00.  It's not accurate to say that no one wants to buy those calls - anyone who wanted to buy one of those calls would just buy it at the ask price of 0.01.

So why are people selling those calls for just 0.01?  The further out of the money you go as you get closer to expiration, the less likely the underlying stock or ETF (SPY in this case) will go over the strike price, and the less you can sell it for.  SPY closed yesterday at about 195, and it would have to go up almost 2.5% today for the 199.50 calls to be in the money, and a 2.5% move in one day is extremely unlikely.